# How to solve this question about convergence of sequence in Banach space?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Let X be a Banach space and $a_{k}^{(n)}\in X$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k=1,2,\cdots,n$. Assume $a_{k}\in X$ be such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\|a_{k}\|<\infty$ and that for all $k$
$$
a_{k}^{(n)}\rightarrow a_{k} \,\,as \,\,n\rightarrow \infty.
$$
Then there exists a sequence $\{K_{n}\}$ converging to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{K_{n}}a_{k}^{(n)}\rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k} \,\,as \,\,n\rightarrow \infty.
$$

I have tried to use triangle inequality
$$
\left\|\sum_{k=1}^{K_{n}}a_{k}^{(n)}- \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}\right\|\leq \left\| 
\sum_{k=1}^{K_{n}}a_{k}^{(n)}- \sum_{k=1}^{K_{n}}a_{k}\right\|+\left\| \sum_{k=K_{n}+1}^{\infty}a_{k}\right\|
$$ 
When $n\rightarrow \infty$ the second term converge to zero, but how to chose ${K_{n}}$ such that the first term converge to zero when $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Try to attack it from the other side. Can you find a sequence $(n_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $$\biggl\lVert \sum_{k = 1}^m a_k^{(n)} - \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k\biggr\rVert \leqslant \frac{1}{m}$$ for all $n \geqslant n_m$ holds for each $m$? Can you then translate $(n_m)$ into a suitable sequence $(K_n)$?

Comment: if $k=1,2,\ldots ,n$ then the expression $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\|a_k\|=\sum_{k=1}^{n }\|a_k\|<\infty $ is trivially true. There is something wrong in your notation

Comment: @Masacroso I read it so that $a_k^{(n)}$ is defined for $k \leqslant n$, and $a_k$ for all $k$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer If $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\left\|\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{k}^{(n)}-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}\right\| \rightarrow \left\|\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty}a_{k} \right\|$, but it doesn't less than $\frac{1}{m}$, so how to chose such $n_{m}$?

Comment: Ah, right. Make it $\leqslant 2 \sum_{k = m+1}^{\infty} \lVert a_k\rVert$. That still tends to $0$ as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I don't know how to convert $n_{m}$ into $K_{n}$.

Comment: Set $K_n = m$ for $n$ in a suitable range.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer If you set $K_{n}=m$, then if you give a bound between $\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{k}^{(n)}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$, you will get $\{K_{n}\}$, but it actually depends on the bound you give and not depends on n.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a sequence $(\varepsilon_m)$ of positive real numbers converging to $0$.

Since $a_k^{(n)} \to a_k$ for every $k$, for every $m$ there is an $N_m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geqslant N_m$ implies $\lVert a_k^{(n)} - a_k\rVert \leqslant \varepsilon_m/m$ for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant m$. We can choose the $N_m$ such that $N_{m+1} > N_m$ for all $m$. Define

$$K_n = \max\: \bigl(\{ \nu \in \mathbb{N} : N_{\nu} \leqslant n\} \cup \{1\}\bigr).$$

Then $K_n \to \infty$, and for $N_m \leqslant n < N_{m+1}$ we have
\begin{align}
\Biggl\lVert \sum_{k = 1}^{K_n} a_k^{(n)} - \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k\Biggr\rVert
&= \Biggl\lVert \sum_{k = 1}^m a_k^{(n)} - \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k\Biggr\rVert \\
&\leqslant \sum_{k = 1}^m \lVert a_k^{(n)} - a_k\rVert + \sum_{k = m+1}^{\infty} \lVert a_k\rVert \\
&\leqslant m\cdot \frac{\varepsilon_m}{m} + \sum_{k = m+1}^{\infty} \lVert a_k\rVert \\
&= \varepsilon_m + \sum_{k = m+1}^{\infty} \lVert a_k\rVert \\
&= \varepsilon_{K_n} + r_{K_n}
\end{align}
where the right hand side tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.